# Custom OK google command

Tags: android

How do we make OK Google to accept custom commands?

Our requirement is simple, we want something like "Appname keyword" to get results and show on our app. Ok Google works with Search for Keyword on Appname, but its too hard since we have to be very fast to make it work, otherwise it searches on web.

I see here, "Note: We are not accepting requests for Custom Voice Actions. Stay tuned to Voice Actions - Google Developers and +GoogleDevelopers for product updates." https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/custom-actions Is there any workaround or other possible actions that I am unaware of?